# Connection not establish in for client server program

Tags: java, sockets

I am very new to socket programming for java. I have develop a simple client server program which involve actionListener. The connection can't be establish once the join button being click, my client program didn't response anything to me. When I run my server program first, the server program response some initial message in the program to indicate that the server is starting, but when I run my client program and try to connect to the server, it will not response anything. Beside, the program is testing using two CMD in my PC

I try several method such as flush(), close() and it also not working 
[Simple client server program not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807028/simple-client-server-program-not-working)  
This is one of my reference source for my problem

This is one part of my client program

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==btn1)
    {
       try
        {
           Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",8888); //initialize the socket in client
           DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); // receive message from server 
           DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  // send the message to server 
           String word = input.readUTF(); // read the input from server 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,word);       // display the message
           output.flush();
           output.close();
           btn2.setVisible(true);
           btn3.setVisible(true);
           btn4.setVisible(true);   
        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Client : Can't Connect To Server, Please Try Again");
        }

    }
```

This is my server program 
http://codepad.org/AlUr9Qi1

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? If so please add them to the question.. If you are getting the message on screen via the OptionPane saying you cant connect. Then just add another line above that ie.... exp.printStackTrace(); That should give you enough info as to what is going on. If not then post the stack trace here and im sure someone can assist.

Comment: No,it just hang like that, that why I cant trace out which part of my program generate the problem

Comment: go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html, especially the last part about writing a server, then it should be clear what you're doing wrong :-)

Comment: Hi, Mateusz.. I will refer the link later on, is it my testing environment correct because I doing it using Jcreator first but I cant create the Jar file,so I change to using cmd

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to me to be in your server code. Your server loops on accept:

```
 while(true)
    {
      socket = server.accept();
    }
```

So you accept the socket and do nothing else, and never reach the code dealing with the socket stream. You need to read/write from the socket inside that loop, possibly spanning a thread to process the socket while continuing waiting for another client.

Comment: i found out some interesting after read some of the comment at here, so do i need to implement knock knock protocol and java thread together or i can only implement it using java thread ?